# Converting byte array/MySQL BLOB to list/Numpy array of float32 in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, arrays, blob

I have a list of float32 numbers stored as BLOB on MySQL, I have the following script to read it from my database, it looks like `mydata` is of type `bytearray`, how can I convert it to a list or Numpy array of type float32?

```
query = ("SELECT mydata FROM mytable LIMIT 0,100")
cursor.execute(query)

for (mydata,) in cursor:
    print mydata  # bytearray(b"\xbe\xefe\x00#\xdf\x10\x...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.frombuffer(mydata, dtype=np.float32)` seems to work.